# Click checkbox with puppeteer via element ID

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have this puppeteer code:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://myurl.com/page");
  await page.waitForSelector("#select-all-checkbox");

  var bodyHTML = await page.content();
  console.log(bodyHTML + "\n\n");

  await page.click("#select-all-checkbox");
  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Logging the HTML to the console, I have verified the page I am accessing has this HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="select-all-checkbox" value="" checked=""><span class="ifaFs"><span data-testid="icon-checkbox-someselected" class="hdDWuD"></span></span></label>
```

I am receiving this error on the **page.click** line:

> (node:3827) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either
>   not visible or not an HTMLElement
>   at ElementHandle._clickablePoint (/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/JSHandle.js:217:13)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   -- ASYNC --
>     at ElementHandle. (/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>     at DOMWorld.click (/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:367:18)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   -- ASYNC --
>     at Frame. (/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>     at Page.click (/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:1037:29)

Comment: I have also confirmed the element is visible by taking a screenshot in puppeteer. While CSS has changed the look of the checkbox, this is it https://i.imgur.com/iUDHTi8.png

Comment: So. I think what you see in the screenshot it's not the check. but the label. Maybe you can try clicking the parent label element.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks @hardkoded

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With my code example above, this was how I resolved the problem.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://myurl.com/page");
  await page.waitForSelector("#select-all-checkbox");

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector("#select-all-checkbox").parentElement.click();
  });

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://myurl.com/page");
  const checkboxEl = await page.waitForSelector("#select-all-checkbox");
  await checkboxEl.click();

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I would `await checboxEl.click()`